# puts line breaking in_branch in git gem?

Tags: ruby, git

I'm automating a bit of git workflow and have found some curious behaviour when using the [git gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/git/1.2.9.1)'s in_branch method and wondered if anyone could explain why or how this issue occurs? Here's some test code that should reproduce the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'git'

# git details
repo_name = 'SOME_REPO'
working_dir = "#SOME_DIR/git_test_repo"
repo_owner = 'SOME_GIT_USER'
repo_host = 'SOME_GIT_HOST'
repo_dir = "#{working_dir}/#{repo_name}"
remote_repo = "git@#{repo_host}:#{repo_owner}/#{repo_name}.git"
branch_name = 'testbranch'
commit_message = 'log line breaking in_branch test'

Dir.mkdir(working_dir) unless Dir.exist?(working_dir)
Dir.chdir(working_dir)
Git.clone(remote_repo, repo_name) unless Dir.exists?(repo_dir)

repo = Git.open(repo_dir)
repo.pull(remote = 'origin', branch = 'master')
repo.branch(branch_name).in_branch(message = commit_message) do
  File.write(repo_dir + '/test.txt', Time.now)
  repo.add('.')

  # -----this line breaks it --------------
  puts 'committing changes'
  # ---------------------------------------

end
```

When this code runs, the last puts line before the end of the in_branch block, when actually run, somehow causes the changes in the branch to be reverted, but when it's commented out, all the code behaves as expected. I've tested output lines anywhere in the block, and they all behave fine. It seems to happen across many versions of ruby (custom installs, rvm installs) and different OS's (linuxes and mac).

Is there some arcane behaviour of ruby and its terminal output I need to be aware of here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really "arcane behavior of ruby".  But the result of the last line in a method is what the method returns.  Putting a `puts` in that position will usually break the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just testing and I see the same behavior using print (which does not add a newline).

This is not a newline issue, moving the (now print) line above the repo.add line and all works.

Anymore thoughts?